# Stop a NiFi processor group as soon as the execution is completed

Tags: apache-nifi

I am starting and stopping a processor group containing a flow of custom processors, via API.

How can I make the processor group run only once and just stop?

We can use a cron to get it executed only once. But is there a clean way, without the need to calculate the cron expression and executing it only once?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your flow you can use **InvokeHTTP** processor (or) **trigger shell script** and making use of **process group REST API** you can **stop all the processors** in the process group.

Schedule your trigger processor in your process group to run on Timer Driven with **1000000000000 sec** and Using another InvokeHTTP processor (or) using Shell script you can start this processor.

**Flow:**

[image]

You can either stop your **trigger processor** (or) stop the **entire process group**.

If you are stopping the entire process group then you need to keep **InvokeHTTP** processor that **starts the process group** needs to be in different process group.

Comment: Is there a more clean way of doing? Without exposing the any additional processors?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the InvokeHTTP processor when finish to call the nifi-api.

[Here](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/110096/start-process-group-using-nifi-rest-api.html) you can find an interesting article explaining how to do this.